# ng-class removes a class but does not put it back

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

In angular.js, I'm trying to apply a set of classes based on the value of a variable on `$scope`. But when I set a pair of space-delimited classes, ng-class seems to be removing any that are already present (and it doesn't put them back).

See the Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fLf0fenj/

Try clicking any of the gray buttons. An icon will appear. It's one from Font Awesome, and the class is `fa fa-whatever`. Now click another of the gray buttons. The icon *should* turn into another Font Awesome icon, but instead of that element having two classes (`fa fa-something-else`), it just has the `fa-something-else`, so it looks like a square.

If you instead click a gray button, and then the green button, it's all fine. Because that green button uses a glyphicons icon, and so the class names are all being switched out each time.

How do I get around this behavior?

Comment: Seems like you don't need the `ng-class` here, try using only `class` like: http://jsfiddle.net/fLf0fenj/2/

Comment: Isn't this more fun - http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/dg4rpadr/

Comment: @Dylan that does indeed look much nicer than mine ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ng-class="statusIcon()"
```

And here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y98pdzc6/)

Comment: I ended up doing something like this where `statusIcon()` just appends the other classes that always need to be there, like `fa` and `status-icon`. Not sure why the behavior of the bracket syntax in ng-class isn't the same as the function syntax though.